# Clicking a Button in a Form produces "The resource cannot be found"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Details page which displays the event details.

There is a Register button at the bottom of this page.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Events", new { eventId = Model.Id }, FormMethod.Post, null))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div id="">
    <p>
        @*<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btnEnrol" name="btnEnrol" value="@Model.Id" title="Register">Register</button>*@
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btnEnrol" name="btnEnrol" value="Register" />
    </p>
</div>
}
```

Here is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(int eventId)
{
    if (eventId == 0)
        return View("Index");

    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var registration = this.repo.GetRegistration(eventId, userId);

    if (registration != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Registered = true;
    }
    else
    {
        var successful = this.repo.RegisterEvent(eventId, userId);

        if (successful)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

And here is the link after clicked the Register button

> http://localhost/lrc/Events/Register?eventId=7

And here is the RouteConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    name: "Home",
    //    url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
    //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    //);

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I have read through many posts on SO, but none of them solve my problem.

Something I have also tried:

removed the [HttpPost] annotation, I don't think it helps but it's just a desperate attempt.

---

**Update 1**

I added 1 more route in the RouteConfig.cs before the default route:

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
    //routes.MapRoute(
    //    name: "Home",
    //    url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
    //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    //);url: "Event/Register/{eventId}"

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "myRoute",
        url: "Events/Register/{eventId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Register", eventId = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And then I finally got something different, but it's still an error:

> Server Error in '/lrc' Application.
>
> The current type,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[lrc.Models.ApplicationUser], is
>   an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The current type,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[lrc.Models.ApplicationUser], is
>   an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: The current type,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[lrc.Models.ApplicationUser], is
>   an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?]
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.ThrowForAttemptingToConstructInterface(IBuilderContext
>   context) +192    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +40
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +48
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +323
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +349
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey
>   newBuildKey) +254    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +200
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +48
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +323
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +349
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey
>   newBuildKey) +254    lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +202
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext
>   context) +48
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +323
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context) +349
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +442
>
> [ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type
>   = "lrc.Controllers.AccountController", name = "(none)". Exception occurred while: while resolving. Exception is:
>   InvalidOperationException - The current type,
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[lrc.Models.ApplicationUser], is
>   an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?
>   ----------------------------------------------- At the time of the exception, the container was:
>
> Resolving lrc.Controllers.AccountController,(none)   Resolving
>   parameter "userManager" of constructor
>   lrc.Controllers.AccountController(lrc.ApplicationUserManager
>   userManager, lrc.ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
>       Resolving lrc.ApplicationUserManager,(none)
>       Resolving parameter "store" of constructor lrc.ApplicationUserManager(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[[lrc.Models.ApplicationUser,
>   lrc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] store)
>         Resolving Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.IUserStore`1[lrc.Models.ApplicationUser],(none)
>   ]    Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object
>   existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +550
>
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String
>   name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +20
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +78
>
> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a
>   controller of type 'lrc.Controllers.AccountController'. Make sure that
>   the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext
>   requestContext, Type controllerType) +256
>   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext
>   requestContext, String controllerName) +169
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory)
>   +270    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +147
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +12289179    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

---

**Update 2**

Here is my EventsController constructor

```
    private ILRCRepository repo;

    public EventsController(ILRCRepository repository)
    {
        this.repo = repository;
    }
```

I searched the UserStore throughout the entire project and found it at only one place (inside the IdentityConfig.cs):

```
// Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
```

Comment: what is `Irc`? are you using areas?

Comment: hi @StephenMuecke it's just the name of my website

Comment: Does not look to be anything wrong with the code. You have the `[Authorize]` attribute but the method is named `Register` suggesting the user is not yet logged in (so would no be authorized). Have you tried with `[AllowAnonymous]`?

Comment: hi@StephenMuecke I agree that the code should be alright. I need [Authorize] as only registered users can register an event.

Comment: Have you tried creating a specific route (before the default) - with `url: "Event/Register/{eventId}",`

Comment: @Franva - just to clarify, the `Register` action DOES exist in the `EventsController`, right?

Comment: hi@StephenMuecke the url pattern does not match my url: events/register?eventId=7. Do I need to do it like : Events/Register?eventId={eventId} ?

Comment: hi @ethorn10 I posted my Register action method in my question.

Comment: @Franva - I know the method exists, but is it in the proper controller (Events)?

Comment: @Franva, No, it needs to be as I stated - `url: "Event/Register/{eventId}"` Not sure what you mean by _"url pattern does not match"_. But I don't know why you want to have `.../Events/Register?eventId=7` instead of the normal `.../Events/Register/7`

Comment: hi @ethorn10 yes, it's in the EventsController.

Comment: hi @StephenMuecke it's because the BeginForm() generates that url.

Comment: @Franva, That has nothing to do with it. All I was suggesting was if your added a specific route `url: "Event/Register/{eventId}"` then it would generate `.../Events/Register/7` instead of `.../Events/Register?eventId=7` There appears to be nothing wrong with your code as it is.

Comment: hi @StephenMuecke, please see my Update 1 part.

Comment: @Franva, That error is not related to any code in your question. It appears to be an issue related to `Unity`. I assume your using DI to inject an interface in to the controllers constructor. Can you show the constructor for `EventController`

Comment: What does `repo.GetRegistration()` return? The error message states your trying to initialize an interface (which cant be done). Suggest you need to debug your code to determine which line of code is throwing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Post will work fine.  And as @Stephen noted in the comments, post with an action parameter should work just fine.

As an alternative, if for some reason it doesn't work, you can use a hidden field for the event ID:

```
Html.Hidden("eventId", Model.Id)
```

And this will post to the action just fine.

Comment: OP is adding the value as a route parameter and it will post back and be bound. A hidden input is not necessary

Comment: I thought I tried this once before and had to use a hidden input field; i could be wrong.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: hi Brian, then how do I get the id?

Comment: You can just define eventId in your action method parameter list as you have above, and it will work with the way you have setup.  Are you trying the hidden variable approach then, or is the querystring working?

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting the resource cannot be found has to do with your RouteConfig.cs expecting an {id} and your `EventsController` expecting an {eventId}.

Change your EventsController method to have `int id` as the input parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Register(int id)
{
    if (id == 0)
        return View("Index");

    var now = DateTime.Now;

    var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

    var registration = this.repo.GetRegistration(id, userId);

    if (registration != null)
    {
        ViewBag.Registered = true;
    }
    else
    {
        var successful = this.repo.RegisterEvent(id, userId);

        if (successful)
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Or alternately, you could update your RouteConfig.cs to include a route with {eventId}:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Event",
            url: "{Irc}/Events/Register/{eventId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Events", action = "Register", eventId = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: hi ethom10, thank you for your help. I have checked the eventId to id and added the route in the RouteConfig.cs, but problem persists.

Comment: @Franva yeah it looks like your problem quickly left the area of routing and into dependency injection.

Comment: I agree, it now shows a different error related to Unity DI.